# Why does this recursion return 0?

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
def bounce(n):
    if n < 1: 
        return 0 #if I change this value to 1 n gets printed out correctly, why?
    else:
        return n * bounce(n - 1)


print(bounce(5))
```

Comment: Because everything multiplies 0 equals 0 ?

Comment: but why does the if statement still run, 5>1

Comment: Why don't you [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) this by printing out the value of n? You'll quickly see the problem.

Comment: @newbieZ No it doesn't run until it reaches n = 0, at which point, it zeros. out everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base case is `return 0`. After the line `return n * bounce(n - 1)` where n is 1, `bounce(0)` will be executed, returning 0 and multiplying all your previous results by 0.

Following the calls, we see:

- 5>=1, so return `5*bounce(4)`
- 4>=1, so return `5*4*bounce(3)`
- 3>=1, so return `5*4*3*bounce(2)`
- 2>=1, so return `5*4*3*2*bounce(1)`
- 1>=1, so return `5*4*3*2*1*bounce(0)`
- 0<1, so return `5*4*3*2*1*0`

meaning everything gets zeroed out at the end.
You want the base case to be 1 for that reason.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this makes much more sense now!

Comment: Doesn't "base case" refer to the input, not the output?

Answer (score 1):

You sould add an check that returns the value for 0.
Otherwise you recursion multiplys with 0 at the final call of the recursiv function.

```py
def bounce(n):
   if n < 1:
      return 0
   elif n == 1:
      return 1
   else:
       return n * bounce(n - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This recursion is returning `0` because when `n = 1`, your compiler goes inside the `else` block and calls `return 1 * bounce(0)`, and this time the compiler returns `0` because the `if`-condition is satisfied here. If you want your output to be `120` (in this case), you can change your code like this:

```py
def bounce(n):
    if n < 1: 
        return 0
    else :
        if n == 1:
            return n ;
        return n * bounce(n - 1)

print(bounce(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a loop that will continually repeat until you get to the point that n = 0, and you are printing a product where at least one value has "n * 0" in it.